# Can't access new droplet created from snapshot of another droplet

Tags: apache, digital-ocean, centos6.5

I'm new to server management, so please forgive what might be a silly question...

I created a new droplet from a snapshot taken from another droplet which is currently live. Both droplets are the same configuration except that one is on NYC3 and the other on TOR1.

The new droplet does not have a domain name associated with it yet so I am trying to access it in my browser by IP address (159.203.11.178).

The new droplet can be accessed at this IP address via PuTTY, but if I type the address into my browser, the site won't load. Actually, it looks like it's caught in a loop.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Cheers, Arnold

Comment: I am not sure but you need to check the Nginx configurations. please check ```server_name``` in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/your_nginx_configfile. Replace your new IP with old one. Let me know if any query.

Comment: I'm using an Apache server so the setup is slightly different than yours, though still easy to sort through. It turns out this was a simple problem within the app where an address was incorrect, and not a server problem at all!